# Html select options from given array not showing

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm working on a React App. I have multiple select tags and different options to display and I wrote a function that receives the options and returns the whole select tag. I call this function multiple times from the render() method. I wanted to reuse the code. For some reasons the select options and not showing.

My code is something like that:

```
DisplayMenu = (id, options) => {

let menu = <div className="model"> Model 
                 <select id={id}>
                   {
                     this.options.map( (item, index) => {
                       <option value={index}>{item}</option>
                     })
                   }
                 </select>
               </div>
return menu;


}

render(){
   
   return (
      <div id="main">
           // other <p> elements here
           <Collapsible trigger="Actors">
             {this.DisplayMenu("FirstActor", this.props.Details["FirstActor"])}
             {this.props.Details["OtherActors"].map ( ( item, index) => 
               this.DisplayMenu("OtherActor" + index, item)
               )}
           </Collapsible>

         //oher <button> tags here

         </div>      


)
}
```

The functions displays the select tag but options are empty. My arrays are good, I checked the values. I assumed that the cause may be the z-index value for the  tag, I tried to chage it but again nothing is displayed. Also in the browser console this is displayed:

```
<select id="FristActor model "></select> ==$0
```

Any ideas will help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning from your map function

```
<select id={id}>
   {
     this.options.map( (item, index) => {
       return <option value={index}>{item}</option>
     })
   }
 </select>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I missed. Oh such a silly mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i'm not able to comment due to less reputation.

Updating Kumar's answer if you not want to write return.

```js
<select id={id}>
   {
     this.options.map( (item, index) => (
       <option value={index}>{item}</option>
     ))
   }
 </select>
```

Thanks.